# Reset pointer position of an array of strings within a function in c

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to reset the position of a pointer at the beginning by using a function. My idea was to send to the function the address of the array of strings. By decrementing the pointer it should also be decreased in memory so I should be able again to manipulate my pointer from the beginning once getting back in my main function, but this seems not working and the position remains unaltered.

```
    void reset(char ***g,int count){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
          g--;
        }
    }
```

and in the main:

```
char **array_of_strings = malloc etc....
//doing my operations and incrementing the pointer position
reset(&array_of_strings,count); //where count is how many time position of array_of_strings has been incremented 
free(array_of_strings); //invalid pointer position
```

I also assume that making a function which returns a new pointer with the decreased position it's useless because we are not able to free the original pointer yet, it could be useful in another context maybe but not in this one.

Comment: How is `g--` going to be correct? `g` is a local variable in the `reset` function. Perhaps you need something like `*g--`? P.S. This was from a really quick overview. This just seemed wrong in your code

Comment: @SuraajKS in the beginning, I thought the same, but it does not work in this way too

Comment: `//doing my operations with the pointer` is a bad idea. Better would be to just remember the pointer you got ftom malloc(). If you need an extra pointer (or index) just declare another pointer.

Comment: I agree with @wildplasser. It is better to use another pointer to iterate your array of strings

Comment: @wildplasser whatever number of alias pointers I use, I need to free them at the end and at least one of them will have the same problem because of the bad position. my idea was to create a function wich recycle this process because the "for cycle" works correctly in the main function.

Comment: @SuraajKS shouldn't that be ```(*g)--``` instead of ```*g--```?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Yes

Comment: @Virgula : no you don't need to free them all. You only need to free the objects whose pointers were obtained by malloc. One malloc() -->> one free()

Comment: @wildplasser understood, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to decrement in a loop. It is simple pointer arithmetic. In the example below you have some examples

```
char *strings[] = {"111","222","3333","4444", "555", NULL};

char **strptr = strings;

char ** pointerartihm(char **ptr, ssize_t count)
{
    return ptr + count;
}

char **threestar(char ***ptr, ssize_t count)
{
    *ptr += count;
    return *ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    ssize_t count = 0;
    while(*strptr) {printf("%s\n", *strptr++); count++;}

    //strptr -= count;
    //strptr = pointerartihm(strptr, -count);
    threestar(&strptr, -count);

    printf("\n\n After the \"reset\" - %s\n", *strptr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qbvz9G

Comment: hello thanks for posting your solution. iI tied to adapting what you wrote here: https://godbolt.org/z/YGrz8s it works by freeing strptr but not strings

Comment: Or is it useless to free(strings) once done free(strptr) because they point at the same memory address?

Comment: @Virgula a lots of issues. You do  not allocate enough memory. And in my example the pointer array has to be NULL terminated to work. https://godbolt.org/z/86xoxr

Comment: yeah, I have not allocated enough memory because I wrote it quickly. Anyway, I understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is basically like this:

```
int i = calculate_something();
// doing my operations and incrementing i
// how do I get i back to the number I calculated?
```

And the answer is, you use a separate variable:

```
int i = calculate_something();
int j = i;
// doing my operations and incrementing j
// now i still has the original number
```

With pointers:

```
char **array_of_strings = malloc etc....
char **temp_pointer_to_array_of_strings = array_of_strings;
// doing my operations and incrementing the pointer position of the second one
// now array_of_strings still has the original pointer
free(array_of_strings); // valid
```